# Некорректный перенос слов в TextView

Tags: android, textview

В гугле ответа на свой вопрос не нашел.
Есть следующий layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/guide_container"
    android:visibility="visible">




    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/subguide_container">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/timer_work"
            android:src="@drawable/time"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/guide_play_icon"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/guide_play_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/play"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/guide_subitem_icon"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"

            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
        <!--android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"-->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/guide_subitem_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/i"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/guide_subitem_time"
            android:text="12:00"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="НеНовости"
            android:id="@+id/name_show_guide"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/guide_subitem_time"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/guide_subitem_time"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/guide_play_icon"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name_show_guide"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name_show_guide"
            android:id="@+id/about_show_container"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/guide_play_icon"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/guide_play_icon">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="О шоу"
                android:id="@+id/guide_subitem_about_show" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="осталось"
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_below="@+id/about_show_container"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name_show_guide"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:singleLine="false" />


        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/guide_subitem_progressbar"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="95"

            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/horiz_progressbar_style_1_3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name_show_guide"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="-8dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/notification_container"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Уст. напомин."
        android:id="@+id/textView28"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView28"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView28"
        android:src="@drawable/no_start"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView10"
        android:src="@drawable/no15"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/nopasaran"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

TextView с id "name_show_guide" отображается так, меня это не устраивает, а как исправить не знаю. Подскажите если у кого есть идеи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: акакие именно символы у вас выступают пробелами? Если это специальный пробел, который не разрывает строку, тогда проблема именно в этом. Поумолчанию TextVIew работает именно так, как вам надо - переносит по словам

Comment: Большое спасибо, твой ответ помог мне найти в коде место где все портилось(при парсинге ответа из сети):
                    String title="";
                    if (item.getString("title").length()>25){
                        title=item.getString("title").substring(0,26)+"\n"+splitterTitle(item.getString("title").substring(26,item.getString("title").length()));
                    } else {
                        title=item.getString("title");
                    }
Можешь перенести свой комментарий в ответ я засчитаю его как ответ - мне помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, пробеламы в вашем тексте выступают не обычные пробелы, а так называемые `Non-breaking space`. В HTML это `&nbsp;`, Unicode - код смвола - `U+00A0`. Если это так, то этот символ попросту не считается пробелом, и слова, разделенные этим символом считаются одним большим словом.